# Long processing on the server. How to deal with timeout and client feedback?

Tags: php, email

to cut costs with mailchimp, I'm building an e-mail marketing sender for my website in PHP.

Basically I have my list in a database (now it's about 7k). It sends using sparkpost API. It does that by executing a for loop that gets the list's emails and send them one by one.

```
    foreach ($contacts as $contact) {
        $data = [
            'campaign' => $campaign,
            'group' => $group,
            'contact' => $contact,
        ];

        Mail::send('mail', $data, function ($message) use ($data) {
                $message->from($data['campaign']->femail, $data['campaign']->fname);
                $message->to($data['contact']->email, $data['contact']->name)->subject($data['campaign']->subject);
        });
    }
```

My problem is: this loop might take a very long time if there are too many e-mails, and I'm not sure how the server or the client will behave (if it will timeout and maybe have the sending incomplete)

My question: What's a good way to deal with this? How could I make sure that the server executes the full task, while the client could be able to view some sort of progress, or maybe receive an e-mail once sending is done?

Comment: some sort of logging perhaps.....

Comment: do the records have incrementing ids? if yes then how about doing them in batches of 500 or 1000. just keep getting the next batch until no records returned.

Comment: You can add a flag field ( a boolean called sent maybe ) and send then in batches of 500, updating the field as you go to true.